# Something wrong with QGraphicsScene y-acxis

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have a simple example with QGraphicsScene wrong behavior

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    //background
    ui->graphicsView->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::black);

    QLineF y_line(ui->graphicsView->sceneRect().center().x(), ui->graphicsView->sceneRect().center().y() - 100,
                  ui->graphicsView->sceneRect().center().x(), ui->graphicsView->sceneRect().center().y() - 550);

    QLineF x_line(ui->graphicsView->sceneRect().center().x() - 100, ui->graphicsView->sceneRect().center().y(),
                  ui->graphicsView->sceneRect().center().x() - 550, ui->graphicsView->sceneRect().center().y());

    scene->addLine(y_line, QPen(Qt::yellow));
    
    //add line X
    scene->addLine(x_line, QPen(Qt::green));
    ui->graphicsView->fitInView(ui->graphicsView->sceneRect());
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I uave this:
[image]

And this is ok, i think
BUT

if i comment out add line X

i have this :

[image]

How you can see the line direction!! changed .

How somebody can explain this???
Wrong behavior  i think? some bugs in Qt?

Comment: commit it is like this:  //scene->addLine(x_line, QPen(Qt::green));
i can't post two simples of code here because of site politic , they print "sore much code"

Comment: exactly , i have changed it in the post, thanks

Comment: Yes, i know, but it doesn't about size , it is about direction , and i have graphicsview minimum size by designer. I think something going wrong

Comment: in Qt docs looks like it is not necessary to set sceneRect